# Why does JavaFX HTMLEditor not display text where editor is displayed in a Dialog?

Tags: javafx, dialog, html-editor

I'm having a problem displaying text in an `HTMLEditor` that is displayed in a JavaFX `Dialog` window. See end of message for app code that illustrates the problem.

**Objective**: Display and edit text in an `HTMLEditor` that has been set to the content for the `dialogPane` in a `Dialog` window.

**Problem**: The text in the `HTMLEditor` is invisible. It is there (see "Observations" below), but it cannot be seen.

**Test app notes**: Both buttons have the same `onAction` value (`actionHandler` in the app code). Clicking either button initializes the dialog and `dialogEditor` before the dialog is displayed. If "Button#1" is clicked the `htmlText` for `dialogEditor` is initialized with the `htmlText` from `appHtmlEditor`. Clicking Button#2 initializes the `dialogEditor` with the `sampleText` value (which appears below the buttons). If the dialog is closed by clicking 'OK' the `htmlText` value for `dialogEditor` is returned and set to the `htmlText` for `appHtmlEditor`.

**Observations**: Clicking Button#2 displays the dialog, ... but without the `sampleText` appearing, although the `sampleText` is there because if the dialog is closed immediately by clicking the 'OK' button the `htmlText` from `dialogEditor` (which - again - is invisible) is returned and set to the `htmlText` value for `appHtmlEditor`, which causes that `htmlText` to change.

The problem clearly has something to do with using `HTMLEditor` and `Dialog` together. I've used `Dialog` in the same way in other contexts without any problem, and the `HTMLEditor` in the demo app itself also functions properly. But for some reason, using `HTMLEditor` as a `Dialog` child as described here isn't working. FWIW, I've tried using a `Stage` in place of `Dialog` and the result is the same, which suggests that the problem isn't directly related to `Dialog` and is due to some incompatibility between `HTMLEditor` and `Window` ... but I leave that to others who have forgotten more than I will ever know about this stuff.

```
public class HtmlEditorDialogTestApp extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    initializeButtonBoxAndButtons()
                                   .initializeLabelBox()
                                   .initializeSeparator()
                                   .initializeHtmlEditor()
                                   .initializeRoot();
    display(stage);
}

private Button button1, button2;
private HBox buttonBox, labelBox;
private Label labelTag;
private Text sampleText;
private Separator separator;
private HTMLEditor appHtmlEditor, dialogEditor;
private Dialog<String> dialog;
private VBox root;

private EventHandler<ActionEvent> actionHandler = e -> {

    // Create and initialize dialogEditor
    if (Objects.isNull(dialogEditor))
        dialogEditor = new HTMLEditor();
    if (e.getSource() == button1)
        dialogEditor.setHtmlText(appHtmlEditor.getHtmlText());
    else if (e.getSource() == button2)
        dialogEditor.setHtmlText(sampleText.getText());
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("how did this happen?!!");


    // Create and initialize dialog
    if (Objects.isNull(dialog))
        dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setHeaderText("HTMLEditor Dialog");
    dialog.setResultConverter((buttonType) -> {
        return buttonType.getButtonData() == ButtonData.OK_DONE
             ? dialogEditor.getHtmlText()
             : null;
    });


    // Initialize dialog pane
    dialog
          .getDialogPane()
          .setContent(dialogEditor);
    dialog
          .getDialogPane()
          .getButtonTypes()
          .addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);


    // Display dialog and handle return
    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent()) {
        String resultText = result.get().length() > 0
             ? result.get()
             : "empty String (\"\")";
        System.out.println("result text: " + resultText);
        appHtmlEditor.setHtmlText(resultText);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("nothing new from dialog editor!");


    // Cleanup
    dialog = null;
    dialogEditor = null;
};



private HtmlEditorDialogTestApp initializeButtonBoxAndButtons() {
    // Create and initialize buttonBox
    buttonBox = new HBox();
    buttonBox.setSpacing(10);
    buttonBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    // Create and initialize textFromEditorButton
    button1 = new Button("Button#1: Open dialog with editor text");
    button1.setOnAction(actionHandler);

    // Create and initialize textFromLabelButton
    button2 = new Button("Button#2: Open dialog with label text");
    button2.setOnAction(actionHandler);

    // Add buttons to buttonBox
    buttonBox
             .getChildren()
             .addAll(button1, button2);

    return this;
}

private HtmlEditorDialogTestApp initializeLabelBox() {
// Create and initialize labelBox, labelTag and sampleText
    labelBox = new HBox();
    labelBox.setSpacing(5);
    labelTag = new Label("Sample text ->      ");
    sampleText = new Text("Explicit text to initialize HTMLEditor in dialog");
    labelBox
            .getChildren()
            .addAll(labelTag, sampleText);

    return this;
}

private HtmlEditorDialogTestApp initializeSeparator() {
    separator = new Separator();
    VBox.setMargin(separator, new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0));

    return this;
}

private HtmlEditorDialogTestApp initializeHtmlEditor() {
    // Create & initialize htmlEditor
    appHtmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
    appHtmlEditor.setPrefHeight(350);
    appHtmlEditor.setPrefWidth(600);
    appHtmlEditor.setHtmlText("Original text for htmlEditor");

    VBox.setVgrow(appHtmlEditor, Priority.SOMETIMES);

    return this;
}

private HtmlEditorDialogTestApp initializeRoot() {

    // Create and initialize root
    root = new VBox();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    root.setSpacing(5);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    root.setStyle(
                  "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                       "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                       "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                       "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                       "-fx-border-color: cornflowerblue;");

    // Add children to root
    root
        .getChildren()
        .addAll(
                buttonBox,
                labelBox,
                separator,
                appHtmlEditor);

    return this;
}

private void display(Stage stage) {

    // Create scene and display
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setWidth(600);
    stage.setHeight(350);
    stage.setTitle("HTMLEditor Dialog Application");
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Would be grateful for a solution, or if one isn't available (because this is a bug) then maybe a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: this app work fine for me.

Comment: @mr mcwolf - Thanks, the app should work fine. But more importantly, does the text appear not only in the HTMLEditor in app but also in the HTMLEditor in the dialog?

Comment: In light of mr mcwolf's comment - and assuming HTMLEditor in the dialog displays text when he runs the app - it may be useful to know that I'm working with Java 9 and Eclipse Oxygen as the IDE. The problem was encountered in the course of updating JavaFX controls created under Java 8, which shouldn't make any difference but maybe it does.

Comment: I use java 8 and intellij over linux. the app works just as you describe it needs to work.

Comment: @mr mcwolf - interesting about java 8 / intellij / Linux, my OS is Windows 10. Still have the java 8 configuration, but needs some update for something unrelated before test can run, that will say whether it's a Java 9 problem.

Comment: Just tested a configuration under Java 8 that is virtually the same as the one described in the question. That works, so the problem has something to do with Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a bug. A bug report has been submitted and can be tracked at:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8192059